# R: simulation of longitudinal data with an ordered categorical variable

Tags: r, simulation, categorical-data, longitudinal

I'm trying to simulate longitudinal data for my research. The data must contain a categorical variable and another ordered categorical variable. To do this, I'm using the `simstudy` R package, which can simulate longitudinal data.

1- For the simple categorical variable (`var_c_3m`), I am able to do so with the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(simstudy)

def <- defData(varname = "id", formula = "1:10") # Creating identifiers

## Longitudinal data with varying observation and interval times 
## Source: https://kgoldfeld.github.io/simstudy/articles/longitudinal.html
def <- defData(def, varname = "nCount", dist = "noZeroPoisson", formula = 6) 
def <- defData(def, varname = "mInterval", dist = "gamma", formula = 30, variance = 0.01)
def <- defData(def, varname = "vInterval", dist = "nonrandom", formula = 0.07)
df <- genData(n, def)
df <- addPeriods(df)

# nCount defines the number of measurements for an individual
# mInterval specifies the average time between intervals for a subject
# vInterval specifies the variance of those interval times

# Simulating a categorical variable with 3 categories according to the distribution (.5, .3, .2)
def_ <- defDataAdd(varname = "var_c_3m", dist = "categorical", 
                   formula = ".5;.3;.2",
                   variance = "Ibuprofen;Paracetamol;Aspirin")

df <- addColumns(def_, df)
df

    id period time timeID    var_c_3m
 1:  1      0    0      1     Aspirin
 2:  1      1   19      2   Ibuprofen
 3:  1      2   47      3     Aspirin
 4:  1      3   66      4     Aspirin
 5:  2      0    0      5 Paracetamol
 6:  2      1   33      6 Paracetamol
 7:  2      2   81      7   Ibuprofen
 8:  2      3  126      8   Ibuprofen
 9:  2      4  156      9 Paracetamol
10:  2      5  199     10   Ibuprofen
11:  2      6  254     11 Paracetamol
12:  2      7  292     12 Paracetamol
...
48: 10      0    0     48   Ibuprofen
49: 10      1   32     49 Paracetamol
50: 10      2   68     50     Aspirin
51: 10      3   94     51   Ibuprofen
52: 10      4  122     52 Paracetamol
```

2- For the ordered categorical variable, I am trying to create it based on the `df` dataframe, taking the time (here `period`) and for each `id` variables. The simstudy package offers the `genOrdCat()` function, but it seems to work only for cross-sectional data, i.e., when `id` is not repeated as in longitudinal data.

Any solutions to add an ordered categorical variable with `3` categories to my `df` dataframe according to the distribution `(.5, .3, .2)` ***Or another approach*** would be greatly appreciated.

```
    id period time timeID    var_c_3m var_ord_3m
 1:  1      0    0      1     Aspirin          1
 2:  1      1   19      2   Ibuprofen          1
 3:  1      2   47      3     Aspirin          2
 4:  1      3   66      4     Aspirin          3
 5:  2      0    0      5 Paracetamol          1
 6:  2      1   33      6 Paracetamol          1
 7:  2      2   81      7   Ibuprofen          1
 8:  2      3  126      8   Ibuprofen          2
 9:  2      4  156      9 Paracetamol          2
10:  2      5  199     10   Ibuprofen          2
11:  2      6  254     11 Paracetamol          3
12:  2      7  292     12 Paracetamol          3
```